# Why does git remote hang up when pushing lots of tags?

Tags: git, git-tag, bitbucket-server

I was playing around with Git to see if an idea I had would be feasible (essentially tracking version numbers for many files with prefixed tags). I setup a script to generate lots of files and version tags which left me with approximately 45000 tags. We are using Atlassian Stash for our Git server, so I pushed my commits up to a remote repository there without problem, but when I went to push the tags, I got the following error.

```
% git push --tags
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

If I manually push a tag with `git push tagname-1.0` I can push it fine (though it takes a little time). I am currently pushing all my tags with a bash loop, but this has been running for over 24 hours at this point.

Is there some performance issues or limitation with using and/or pushing lots of tags? Is there something wrong with our configuration that might be causing this?

**Edit 1:** I just created a local bare git repo and pushed my many-tags repo to it. I then attempted pushing the tags and got the same remote hang up error, so I do not think this is an issue with Stash.

**Edit 2:** As a temporary work around, I am able to push all branches, 100 at a time, with the following command:

```
git tag | xargs -n 100 git push origin
```

I just attempted to do a local clone to see if I get all my tags as part of the clone and it has taken an incredibly long time (about an hour), but all the tags seem to have transferred correctly. I tried cloning a second time to a new directory and it was much faster, under a minute. Perhaps it reused a pack file or just had more resources available on my machine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Atlassian's Stash, but it would be common for a shared back-end repo to impose limits on both duration and size of particular operations. In addition to that, if you're using HTTP/HTTPS based access to repo, there are also limits in git on HTTP request size (1MB) and git fails with an error if that limit is exceeded. I'd start with checking logs on the server. They may provide a hint what happened.

Comment: Hi Ben, Stash developer here. That's strange that it's just slow on tags. Certainly a large number of refs (eg. tags) can cause problems in Git in general, and 45000 is quite a few. Feel free to raise a support ticket and attach your logs https://support.atlassian.com/.

Comment: @charleso I did some more tests and even using a plain local bare git repo I have the same issues pushing lots of tags, so I do not believe this to be a Stash issue. Let me know if still think there is some support you can provide and I'll try to get you whatever logs you need.

Comment: I have the same issue. I only have 11 tags though. Doesn't seem like that much.